# Showing a clean formatted object documentation in the interpreter?

Tags: python, numpy, textmate

I'm new to python. The thing that I find it annoying so far is not being able to quickly find what an object does or the documentation of a method. I'm coming from Java. In Eclipse for example when you just put a dot after an object it shows you everything you want to see. Ok I understand that Eclipse does support Python as well, but I don't want to use. It's too bulky and heavy to use just for python. I'm using TextMate now along with the interpreter to get quick information about an object.

Like I have an interpreter open in Terminal and whenever I need to check something I type `help(object)`. However today I tried to get the information for `numpy.floor()` function. In Eclipse I tried this and I got the `numpy.floor.__doc__` but when I tried in the interpreter `help(numpy.floor)` I got completely different information! Then I typed in the interpreter `numpy.floor.__doc__` and I got the same information as from Eclipse BUT in a non-formatted way! Like it displays \n \n or \t but not formatting them i.e. it shows them as text!!! Which makes reading the doc very very frustrating. Is there a better way to get the doc, because my productivity is at ITS WORST!!!

Comment: Did you try `print numpy.floor.__doc__`?

Comment: Use ipython, which allows "tab-completion", and you can show docs simply typing `numpy.floor?`

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the output of `help(numpy.floor)`? It answers your question in the second paragraph:

```
floor = class ufunc(builtins.object)
 |  Functions that operate element by element on whole arrays.
 |  
 |  To see the documentation for a specific ufunc, use np.info().  For
 |  example, np.info(np.sin).  Because ufuncs are written in C
 |  (for speed) and linked into Python with NumPy's ufunc facility,
 |  Python's help() function finds this page whenever help() is called
 |  on a ufunc.
```